# How do I bring the control to the field where the form validation has failed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am making a registration form; while making a validation if a field fails the validation test, for eg- If I have not entered the first name, it gives the alert but along with that it gives alerts for all those fields that are empty. I want to send the control to only that field which failed the validation test.In this case First Name. Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment-2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <h3>
    <marquee style="color : Green;">Please Fill all the details correctly</marquee>
  </h3><br>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <h3 class="align-middle">Registration Form</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Eg - Michael">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Eg - Clarke">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Eg-M.c@gmail.com">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="confirm_email" placeholder="type again">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="email">Password:</label>
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="ml-sm-3 ml-md-3"></div>
                <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="ml-sm-3 ml-md-3"></div>
                  <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Male">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="Gender"           name="optradio" value="Male" checked>Male
               </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ml-sm-4 ml-md-3"></div>
                  <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Female">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="Gender"           name="optradio" value="Female">Female
               </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="D.O.R">Date of Registration:</label><br>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="23/07/2018">
                <p id="date"></p>
                <script>
                  function myFunction() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("Date").value;
                    document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = x;
                  }
                </script>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkbox" value="check">
        I Accept all Terms and Conditions
         </label>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <button id="but" onclick="return btnvalidate();">Submit</button>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          function btnvalidate() {
            var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value
            if (fname.length == 0) {
              alert('First Name cannot be Empty');
            }
            var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value
            if (lname.length == 0) {
              alert('Last Name cannot be Empty');
            }
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value
            if (email.length == 0) {
              alert('email cannot be empty!')
            }
            var confirm_email = document.getElementById("confirm_email").value
            if (confirm_email.length == 0) {
              alert('You NEED to confirm the email!')
            }
            if (email != confirm_email) {
              alert('Email Not Matching! Try again');
            }
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value
            if (password.length == 0) {
              alert('password cannot be empty!')
            }
            var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password").value
            if (password != confirm_password) {
              alert('Password Not Matching! Try again');
            }
            var date = document.getElementById("date").value
            if (date.length == 0) {
              alert('Date of Registeration cannot be empty!');
            }
            alert($("input[name='optradio']:checked").val());
            if (!document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
              alert('Checkbox not checked');
              return false;
            }
          }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In other words, you want the first failed input field to be focused? If yes, use something like this: document.getElementById("myAnchor").focus(); For that to work, you must know the ID of the failed elements.

Comment: Just a note, you're including jQuery twice in your example - that's going to cause issues if that's what your "real" code is doing.

Comment: If you meant to say, you want to stop further validation if any of the validation are failed. you can add "return". `if (fname.length == 0) {
              alert('First Name cannot be Empty');
     return;
            }`

Comment: For `first name`, `last name` and `email` you can use `required`. Probably have some other checks in the `<script>` tag

Comment: As a sidenote, the `marquee` element has been deprecated for a while now and most browsers don't support it any longer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `return` inside the body of every `if` statement like so

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment-2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <h3>
    <marquee style="color : Green;">Please Fill all the details correctly</marquee>
  </h3><br>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <h3 class="align-middle">Registration Form</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Eg - Michael">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Eg - Clarke">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Eg-M.c@gmail.com">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="confirm_email" placeholder="type again">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="email">Password:</label>
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="confirm_email">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="ml-sm-3 ml-md-3"></div>
                <label for="Gender">Gender:</label>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="ml-sm-3 ml-md-3"></div>
                  <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Male">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="Gender"           name="optradio" value="Male" checked>Male
               </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ml-sm-4 ml-md-3"></div>
                  <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Female">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="Gender"           name="optradio" value="Female">Female
               </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <label for="D.O.R">Date of Registration:</label><br>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="23/07/2018">
                <p id="date"></p>
                <script>
                  function myFunction() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("Date").value;
                    document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = x;
                  }
                </script>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkbox" value="check">
        I Accept all Terms and Conditions
         </label>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <button id="but" onclick="return btnvalidate();">Submit</button>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          function btnvalidate() {
            var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value
            if (fname.length == 0) {
              alert('First Name cannot be Empty'); return
              return
            }
           
            var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value
            if (lname.length == 0) {
              alert('Last Name cannot be Empty'); return
            }
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value
            if (email.length == 0) {
              alert('email cannot be empty!'); return
            }
            var confirm_email = document.getElementById("confirm_email").value
            if (confirm_email.length == 0) {
              alert('You NEED to confirm the email!'); return
            }
            if (email != confirm_email) {
              alert('Email Not Matching! Try again'); return
            }
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value
            if (password.length == 0) {
              alert('password cannot be empty!'); return
            }
            var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password").value
            if (password != confirm_password) {
              alert('Password Not Matching! Try again'); return
            }
            var date = document.getElementById("date").value
            if (date.length == 0) {
              alert('Date of Registeration cannot be empty!');
            }
            alert($("input[name='optradio']:checked").val());
            if (!document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
              alert('Checkbox not checked');
              return false;
            }
          }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need Javascript for this - the browser has built-in validation features. Just add the attribute `required` to those fields which cannot be empty.

I've reduce your example to the bare necessities to demonstrate this:

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="fName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Eg - Michael" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Eg - Clarke" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="but">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```